# Client channel is not in writable state(NIO) Netty

Tags: tcp, client, netty, nio, channel

client channel is not in writable state in netty . Can any experts guide me to find-out the reason

why the channel is always not in writable state?

since it is not in writable state our threads are in sleep mode. We analyzed the state of threads using Thread dump, added a counter in the following loop and it waits for a minute and then exit from the loop. But i really want to figure-out the reason for not writable state.

Is the channel is remains in ctx after the closing of channel(If the EOF is not send by the client)?

If can this happends (means never in writable state)?

```
while (!ctx.getChannel().isWritable()) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    }
```

Please help.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the selector, or whatever Netty gives you around it, to tell you when the channel is writable. You certainly shouldn't be literally wasting time by sleeping in a loop. The channel state can't change while you're doing that. It is only changed by `select().`

Comment: while (ctx.getChannel().isWritable()) {
   // write something
    } If we put like this it will wait selector to switch channel to write m mode. If channel is in some other state and not able to return back in writable the threads may enter to an infinite loop.

Comment: @JohnChristy Exactly, so don't do that. The channel state isn't magically going to change while you're sleeping. You need to call `select()` to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Superficially, it is because the ChannelBuffer is full, i.e. no more writable bytes.

It could be caused by writing too fast, or the channel is not able to send out any bytes. If you're not writing anything too fast, perhaps it's because the channel never successfully sent out the bytes written.

Comment: We are writing too fast to other client's channel to inform about the disconnection of other clients. If we trying to check a channel writable that is already closed, but server didn't detect the channel closed event, Can this happen ???

Comment: @JohnChristy I'm not using netty, but I hope you have a way to test whether the channel is closed.

Comment: Yes you are right. But If we didn't get the channel closed event (because of network failure)we cannot check whether it is closed or not. If we have a proper network between client and server we can check whether that particular channel is closed.

Comment: @JohnChristy In case of network failure, the normal procedure to detect the other end is dead is to timeout. You can regard this channel as closed if it's not writable for a certain amount of time. If you have control over the other end, you could also do your own keep-alive heart beat poking. If no heart beat is received from the other end for a certain amount of time, the other end is considered dead and the channel not usable.